# how to show blogs archives using panels

Tags: 7, panels, nodes

I created a view to display blog pages.Then i created a blog archive block which shows years.if i click on the years it shows the blog view which i created.now i want to show the archives(year) block in a panel and the blog view in another pane in the same panel page .
Years in left pane and when i click on year it should show the blog view in right side pane in the same panel page.I need help in solving this problem.Thanks in advance.